# revtex4 left and right margins are not the same

Tags: margins, paper-size, revtex

I seem to have a problem with margins. I'm using revtex4 (4-1 messes up my references, but that's not the point).

The preambule is this:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,prc,floats,amsmath,amssymb]{revtex4}
```

And when I compile it I get this:

[image]

How to get the same amount of white space on the same sides?

Comment: You think it is a problem, but this is a class designed for a publication. They'll have done this quite deliberately: it is the _binding offset_ so that after printing and binding everything looks okay. Normally, you should not mess with the layout of publication-ready classes.

Comment: Yeah, but I used, for instance prc settings (physical review letter C) and it came this way, and my teaching assistant publishes in PRC and has nice and centered text...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `centering` option of the [geometry](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package; this implies defining `paperwidth`, `paperheight`, and the margins. For a4paper you could use, for example, something like the following:

```
\usepackage[paperwidth=210mm,paperheight=297mm,centering,hmargin=2cm,vmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
```

EDIT: I am not sure now what is what you want: if you want to have the same value for the right and left margins in all your document (i.e., to have the text centered in the page), then my previous suggestion will do the job. However, if you only want to keep the same values for the inner and outer margins in all the document, then you can simply add the `twoside` class option:

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn,prc,floats,amsmath,amssymb]{revtex4}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid i have to tell you that you seem to have another problem. `revtex4` by default uses `letterpaper` format. Assuming you use a `latex + dvipdf[m[x]]` or `latex + dvips` toolchain it may be that the dvi converter crops to a4paper. That should also be notable throuth the very big bottom page margin (much space between page border and page number). You should use `dvipdfmx -p letter` to convert the dvi or add the a4paper option to your document class (which for some reasons does not work for me right now, that is the reason i stumbled over this question).